# Bootstrap validation on submit only

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap validation for my website with the following example.

http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-methods

This is working fine as like in the example .my problem is - when i focus an input and move on another input without enter a value,the validation messages showing.i only need to show the error messages ,when we click the submit button.
is this possible?

Comment: have you define like this ? : $('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
  }
})

Comment: @ShivaniPatel Thats fine.but i need to trigger only that one.not want to show the error messages on focus

Comment: in form tag having data-toggle="validator" attribute?Please provide fiddle to understand well.